how to kill asyncio inside subprocess?
So my goal:
When i stop app.py, it should wait for the websocket/rabbitmq(s) to stop, then close. For some reason, the process hangs after everything is done. I dont know much about how asyncIo works under the hood. my code so far:
#websockets.py
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
import sys
import signal
import time

async def main():
    global server
    # Start RabbitMQ setup
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    for signame in ('SIGTERM', 'SIGINT'):
        loop.add_signal_handler(getattr(signal, signame), lambda: asyncio.create_task(stop_server()))

    try:
        await setup_rabbitmq()

        # Start the WebSocket server
        server = await websockets.serve(handler, sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])

        # Keep the event loop running
        await server.wait_closed()

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
async def stop_server():
    global server,rabbitmq_connection_reader,rabbitmq_connection
    # Stop the WebSocket server gracefully
    if rabbitmq_connection_reader:
        await rabbitmq_connection_reader.close()
    if rabbitmq_connection:
        await rabbitmq_connection.close()
    if server:
        server.close()
        await server.wait_closed()
    logging.info("Stopping")
    time.sleep(5)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        logger.error(f"Usage: python {sys.argv[0]} <HOST> <PORT>")
        sys.exit(1)  # Exit with an error code
    asyncio.run(main())

and my runner:
#app.py
import subprocess
import logging
import signal

logger = logging.getLogger("main proccess")
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

file_commands = [
    ['python3', 'sockets.py', '0.0.0.0', '5000'],
]

processes = []

def handle_sigterm(signum, frame):
    logger.info("Received SIGTERM. Terminating all subprocesses.")
    for process in processes:
        process.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)
    for process in processes:
        process.wait(30)
    print("All processes have finished.")

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_sigterm)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_sigterm)

for cmd_args in file_commands:
    logger.info(' '.join(cmd_args))
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args[1:], cwd=cmd_args[0])
    processes.append(process)

# Wait for all processes to finish
for process in processes:
    process.wait()

logger.info("All processes have finished.")

The app.py is normally closed with segtrem, and i must use subprocesses. The reason being, it starts ~30 tasks, the websockets is the only one that hangs.
update:
Instead of using subprocess, swtiched to supervisord (inside docker). ref

Do you get to see the Stopping message that is logged in the signal handler?

yes I do, but then the process never closes

good. I will try to experiment on that - but one thing I'd do on this code is to put all the "closing" calls in the signal handler inside "finally: " blocks. No matter the naive way of doing it will be ugly (a stair case of try: finally"s - it will be more robust. But that won't fix your problem, since "Stopping" gets to be logged.

got that. the problem is the process being waited when sigkill arrives was not being waited at all - and stayed as "defunct".

And - thanks again for provding a minimal, self contained example with both files. (ok, some parts where missing, like the rabbitmq objects, but I just nulled then) - without the complete files, I would not being the one to try and find out what was going on, and I doubt someone else would.

So i have tried using loop.close() and get the error ````ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-17' coro=<stop_server() done, defined at ***.py:361> exception=RuntimeError('Cannot close a running event loop')>```
Regarding rabbitmq, they are aio_pika funcs, which rabbitmq_connection_reader and the other one are stopped inside of stop_server

Ok - it turns the problem with the asyncio part was that the signal handler was being entered twice by the asyncio loop. Adding some state check to prevent it waiting on a server that is already stopped resolved it terminating:
# websocketserver.py

# No ops so I could run the code as it was:
rabbitmq_connection_reader = None
rabbitmq_connection = None
# state variable:
shutting_down = False
...

async def stop_server():
    global server,rabbitmq_connection_reader,rabbitmq_connection, shutting_down
    if shutting_down:
        # we are past all this!
        return
    shutting_down = True
    # Stop the WebSocket server gracefully
    if rabbitmq_connection_reader:
        await rabbitmq_connection_reader.close()
    if rabbitmq_connection:
        await rabbitmq_connection.close()
    if server:
        server.close()
        await server.wait_closed()
        print("server stopped at stop_server")
    logging.warning("Stopping")
    await asyncio.sleep(0) 


Then, in your waiting code structure: if you kill the main app when it is stopped on the process.wait() call for a sub-process, that one process never is collected itself within that .wait() call: it is interrupted by the signal.
Adding a layer to that waiting part (and removing the .wait(30) call on the signal handler itself) worked for me here.
(note that previous to closing on this, I instrumented everything and its child with a lot of "print"s  (shorter than "logging.info" :-)  )  and tried loop.stop, loop.close - until I found out it was already fixed by this retry thing on the process.wait on one of my first changes - but it was then hanging on the .wait(30) call inside the handler) :
# app.py

# Wait for all processes to finish
shutdown = False
while processes:
    unfinished_processes = []
    for process in processes:
        try:
            print(f"waiting {process}")
            process.communicate()
            process.wait(timeout=None if not shutdown else 1)
            print(f"{process} terminated")
        except BaseException as e:
            print("retrying processes wait:", e)
            unfinished_processes.append(process)
            shutdown = True
    processes = unfinished_processes

logger.info("All processes have finished.")

And above, in the same file:

def handle_sigterm(signum, frame):
    logger.info("Received SIGTERM. Terminating all subprocesses.")
    for process in processes:
        process.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)
    #for process in processes:
        #process.wait(30)
    print("All processes have finished.")


i had got the following error:
waiting <Popen: returncode: None args: ['python3', 'sockets.py', '0.0.0.0', '5000']>
INFO:websockets.server:server closing
INFO:websockets.server:server closed
INFO:root:Stopping
INFO:main proccess:Received SIGTERM. Terminating all subprocesses.
waiting <Popen: returncode: None args: ['python3', 'sockets.py', '0.0.0.0', '5000']>```

^ was CTRL+C on the app.py

Oh - wait, there was another change I made - for some reason, the signal handler on the websocket server is being entered twice. I created a state variable so that it does nothing the second time it is entered. I am updating here.

There it is - sorry for that. I really went on a lot after fixing this to find the other issue.
